# How to upload data with key_name by Google App Engine bulkloader

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulkloader

I can upload data, but key_name is empty.
How can I use the 'id' in the [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) as the key_name on datastore?

I'like to use 'id' as the key_name, because other data uses the 'id' as the foreign key.
I'm new to Google App Engine.

This is the CSV data.

```
"id","name"
"1","USA"
"2","France"
"3","Italy"
```

This is the [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML)

```
- model: model.testcountry.TestCountry
  connector: csv
  connector_options:
    encoding: utf-8
    columns: from_header
  property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: id
    - property: name
      external_name: name
```

P.S: I'm trying upload data to the local enviroment.

---

**Update**

Thank you for the help, I tried the code, but it does not work well.
The result is strange.

In the terminal window a log message tells me that uploading finished successfully, 
however I cannot find any records in the Google App Engine console (http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/datastore). The datastore is empty, there is no record.

The log message in the terminal window is this

**Entering command**

```
appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --filename=testcountries.csv --kind=TestCountry --url=http://localhost:8080/remote_api --num_thread=1
```

**Result message**

```
Uploading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader/log.log
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
Please enter login credentials for localhost:8080
Email: xxxxxxx
Password for l: 
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20110609.003032.sql3
[INFO    ] Connecting to localhost:8080/remote_api
[INFO    ] Starting import; maximum 10 entities per post
..........
[INFO    ] 100 entities total, 0 previously transferred
[INFO    ] 100 entities (3362 bytes) transferred in 1.9 seconds
[INFO    ] All entities successfully transferred
```

I also tried this, but result was same. The terminal says success but in the Google App Engine console there are no records....

```
import_transform: int
```

PS: I'm using Mac OS X Snow Leopard and Google App Engine launcher.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- import: google.appengine.ext.bulkload.transform
- model: model.testcountry.TestCountry
  connector: csv
  connector_options:
    encoding: utf-8
    columns: from_header
    property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: id
      import_transform: transform.create_foreign_key('TestCountry')
    - property: name
      external_name: name
```